# passing value (through variable) to custom function

Tags: ruby, function, puppet

I'm trying this thing for a while but can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
Here is  sample function (which is similar to the original one, except for the hash, which is generated dynamically in the original one):

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:am_running_oss, :type => :rvalue ) do |args|

        oss = {:linux=>["Slackware", "RedHat", "Caldera"],
               :mac=>["Jaguar", "Lion", "Tiger", "Kodiak"],
               :win=>["Chicago", "Daytona", "Longhorn"]}

        cls = args[0]

        if oss.key?(cls)
            return oss[cls][0]
        else
            return 'undefined'
        end
    end
end
```

and then in my manifest, I have this:

```
$h= am_running_oss($::am_os_type)
notify { "=*=*= amRunningOS <|:|> ${h} =*=*=*=*=*=*=*=": }
```

(am_os_type is a fact, that returns *win*, *mac* or *linux* based on the node type)

I was expecting to see *Jaguar* or *Slackware* as the return value but I get undefined instead. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Is there anything still am I missing in terms of passing the *args* to the  function? Cheers!!

Comment: try `cls = args[0].to_sym`

Comment: thanks @tihon! that doesn't work though. if have the hash like: `{'linux'=>["Slackware",.....` (instead of having `:linux`) and pass a static value from the manifest, like: `$h = am_running_oss('mac')`, then it works. Cheers!!

Comment: add `p args[0]` and `p args[0].class` in the function and see what it is in console

Comment: @tihom: `args[0].class` returns "String" - so is it a `string` vs `symbol` issue? In that case, how do I pass the value to `am_running_oss()` substituting `$::am_os_type` that actually returns a string? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying to my own question, in case google lands someone here looking for the same. The thing worked for me is to is define `cls` like this:

```
cls = args[0].to_sym if args[0].is_a? String
```

Cheers!!